# is there any web api or website for finding some location and its nearest alike location based on longitude and latitude?

Tags: geolocation, latitude-longitude

I have bunch of longitudes and latitudes about some sport venues and gigs.
I want to find a way to get some similar venues in near location of the same venues but I don't have any idea.

I've heard by the help of dbpedia I can do that but to be honest I don't have any idea how can I query dbpedia according to find some nearest venues.

is there any web api/service website for doing such this things?

P.S : I know how to write SPARQLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the example from http://tinyurl.com/6vx7gga It shows how to filter the venues using the area of the main one.